# Creating a UIViewController from code behind in Xamarin

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin, segue, code-behind

I am currently developing an IOS application in Xamarin. I have made a menu that generates 4 different UIViewControllers from codebehind. What I want to do instead is to push these views to pre made UIViewControllers that I have designed in my storyboard, but not connected to the current UIViewController.

Something like this:

```
UIViewController[] control = new UIViewController[DataList.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < control.Length; i++)
{
    if(control[i] == 1)
    {
        control[i] = new ViewControllerGetCar();
        PerformSegue(control[i], null);
    }
    if(control[i] == 2)
    {

    }
}
```

Cannot convert ViewControllerGetCar to UIViewController...
It says that intPtr handle is needed and i dont know what that is. Im also pretty sure that the performsegue wont work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please include the code for ViewControllerGetCar? My guess, you didn't specify the correct constructor there.

Comment: partial class ViewControllerGetCar : UIViewController
 {
  public ViewControllerGetCar (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
  {
  }
 }

Comment: Thank you, that class and constructor seem ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you designed the ViewControllers in your Storyboard, then here's the proper way to instantiate them.

```
MyViewController controller = MyViewController)this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ViewControllerIdentifier");
```

Translated to your example:

```
UIViewController[] control = new UIViewController[DataList.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < control.Length; i++)
{
  if(control[i] == 1)
  {
    control[i] = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ViewControllerGetCar"); // <-- presuming that's the identifier you're using for it inside the Storyboard.
    PerformSegue(control[i], null);
  }
  if(control[i] == 2)
  {
    // presumably here another ViewController is specified, etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It worked, just had to do control[i] = (UIViewController)this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ViewControllerGetCar");. You saved me and my company alot of time.

Comment: Done! Sorry im new here, hehe.